# eigenvalues of sum of matrices: $A$+block matrix are strictly less than eigenvalues of $A$+identity

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ whose sum for rows is 0, can I prove that the $ \lambda_i \left ( \begin{bmatrix} I & 0\\
 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} +A\right ) $ are strictly less than $\lambda_i \left ( \begin{bmatrix} I & 0\\
 0 & I \end{bmatrix} +A\right )$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated .

I know that $\lambda_i \left ( \begin{bmatrix} I & 0\\
 0 & I \end{bmatrix} +A\right )=1+\lambda_i(A)$ but I can't see any relation with $\lambda_i \left ( \begin{bmatrix} I & 0\\
 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} +A\right )$.

Comment: Something is wrong with the statement.  Let $A$ be the $2 \times 2$ matrix $\text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$; then the eigenvalues of $(I \oplus 0) + A$ are $\lambda_1 + 1$ and $\lambda_2$ while the eigenvalues of $(I \oplus I) + A$ are $\lambda_1 + 1$ and $\lambda_2 + 1$.  In particular, they share the eigenvalue $\lambda_1 + 1$ in common.

Comment: @PaulSiegel Maybe the OP means that if all the eigenvalues are in an ordered field (or ring or whatever), then the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix on the left is smaller than the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix on the right and so on... The PSQ is badly written in my opinion and assumptions regarding where the eigenvalues are, are necessary.

Comment: The statement has a better chance of being true with the added condition that the row sums are $0$, but there is no guarantee that the eigenvalues are real.  Do you perhaps want $A$ to be symmetric?

Comment: Ok, let's suppose that A is symmetric. and thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think we can use the following inequality due to Weyl.  Let $A$ and $B$ be Hermitian matrices with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i$, respectively (indexed in descending order so that $\lambda_1$ and $\mu_1$ are the top eigenvalues).  Let $\nu_i$ denote the eigenvalues of $A+B$, indexed in the same way.  Then:
$$\nu_{i+j+1} \leq \lambda_{i+1} + \mu_{j+1}$$
for all $i$ and $j$ for which both sides of the inequality makes sense.

In your case, let $A$ be any Hermitian $2n \times 2n$ matrix and let $B = (I_n \oplus 0_n)$.  Setting $j = 0$ in Weil's inequality, we get:
$$\nu_{i+1} \leq \lambda_{i+1} + \mu_1 = \lambda_{i+1} + 1$$
The right-hand side, as you observed, is the eigenvalue of $A + I_{2n}$.

However, you wanted the inequality to be strict.  I unfortunately don't know the full analysis of the equality case of Weyl's estimates; all I know off the top of my head is that $\nu_1 = \lambda_1 + \mu_1$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ share a principal eigenvector.  This is clearly ruled out by your condition that the row sums vanish, but I don't know what to say about the other eigenvalues.

Comment: Please can you write more details about last observation?